# A very quick question on interpreting upper bounds of a union $S\cup T$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

> Let $S \subset\Bbb{R}$ and $T \subset \Bbb{R}$ be nonempty and
>   bounded. Further suppose that $M$ is an upper-bound of $S \cup T$.

Could someone point out my mistake in the following interpretation please?

$M$ is an upper-bound of $S\cup T$ $\Rightarrow$ $x \leq M $ for all $x \in S \cup T$ $\Rightarrow$ Two possible cases :

[case 1 : $x \in S$]

With $x \in S$ and $x \leq M$, $M$ is an upper bound of $S$ and by the completeness axiom there exists a supremum such that $x \leq \sup(S) \leq M$

[case 2 : $x \in T$]

With $x \in T$ and $x \leq M$, $M$ is an upper bound of $T$ and by the completeness axiom there exists a supremum such that $x \leq \sup(T) \leq M$

Now,intuitively I thought that the following interpretation is correct:

1. For $x \in S \cup T$, **either** $\sup(S) \leq M$ **or** $\sup(T) \leq M$

However, when I look around on the internet the results there seem to suggest that:

2. For $x \in S \cup T$, $\sup(S) \leq M$ **and** $\sup(T) \leq M$.

Continuing from (2) with :

- Therefore $M \geq \max(\sup(S),\sup(T))$
- And finally $M \geq \sup(S \cup T) \geq \max(\sup(S),\sup(T))$

This I am sure is a silly question...but could someone explain why (1.) is wrong and (2.) is correct please?

Comment: 1) and 2) are both correct, but 2) is stronger. It implies 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two cases you wrote down are not mutually exclusive, and so statement $(1)$ is not true in general (assuming that "either-or" refers to exclusive or; if it refers to inclusive-or, then it is implied by $(2)$).

The correct approach, which leads to $(2)$, is to note that since $M$ upper-bounds $S\cup T$, it upper-bounds every element in $S$ *and* every element in $T$ at once, and thus $\sup S\le M$ and $\sup T\le M$.

Comment: Thank you.Does this mean that the division into cases is wrong or merely unecessary?..i suppose that a division into cases is only sensible if they are mutually exclusive as you mentioned...and since M upper bounding S and M upper bounding T are not mutually exclusive..a division is... wrong?

Comment: @HalfAFoot I'd say the casework is unnecessary.

Comment: Suppose one were inclined to provide such a division,would I have to change anything within the cases above? or is it merely the conclusion that (2.) is true from the cases that I got wrong? Thanks again.

Comment: @HalfAFoot You could have actually derived $(2)$ from the cases already.

Comment: yeah? I suppose that is my confusion with the interpretation :-) what is it about the cases that forces me to conclude (2.) rahter than (1.)?

Comment: @HalfAFoot $x$ is actually irrelevant to both statements. The salient point is that $\sup S,\sup T\le M$ - just whether one or noth are true. Thus, I would have ditched those cases and followed the method in this answer.

Comment: ok,thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

Upperbound $M$ of $S\cup T$ is automatically an upperbound of $S$ **and** is automatically an upperbound of $T$.

From this we conclude that $\sup S\leq M$ **and** $\sup T\leq M$.

This tells us that: $$\max(\sup S,\sup T)\leq M$$

From $\sup S\leq M$ **and** $\sup T\leq M$ it follows directly that also $\sup S\leq M$ **or** $\sup T\leq M$.

Comment: Thanks you for the response. Is there a proof for the first sentence you wrote? My book is one of those Heinz 52 intro books, i suspect some fundamental things are being skipped.

Comment: From the fact that $M$ is an upper bound of $S\cup T$ it follows directly that $s\leq M$ for every $s\in S$ (which means exactly that $M$ is an upper bound of $S$). That will do as proof, and similarly it can be proved that $M$ is an upper bound of $T$. Actually it is so simple that it looks more like an "observation" than a "proof".

Comment: great! thank you for your time.

Comment: You are welcome.